# Convert parts of [UInt8] into UInt8

Tags: swift, integer-arithmetic

I am writing an app for my bachelor-project in electrical engineering and I am working with a byte array which represents a hexadecimal string. The received byte array looks like this:

> | sync | cmd | length | msg | msg | msg | MSB | LSB |

My question is how can I get the all the "msg"s out of the byte array and make them into a number? 
The "length" byte in [2] describes how many of the "msg"s there will be so I wanna use this to calculate the number of array indexes to make into a number.

```
var receivedBytes: [UInt8] = []
func serialDidReceiveBytes(_ bytes: [UInt8]) {
    receivedBytes = bytes
print(receivedBytes)
}
```

> [204, 74, 3, 0, 97, 168, 209, 239]

I want this to become:

```
var: [UInt8] = [0, 97, 168]
```

Make it hecadecimal like:

```
[0x00,0x61,0xA8]
```

Then make this number into 0x61A8 or decimal 25000.

Comment: What's the rule to convert [204, 74, 3, 0, 97, 168, 209, 239] to [0, 97, 168]. It's always 4th, 5th, 6th elements of origin array or something else?

Comment: You say the length is passed along. Is there a maximum for the number of `msg` bytes? Can you have more than 8 (i.e. 64 bits)?

Comment: Also, what the endianness of the data? What's the relevance of those last two cells with MSB and LSB?

Comment: The amount of message bytes can be a maximum of 255 and the amount of them will always be sent as the length-byte in index [2] of the array. In reality these message bytes will represent a number from very small up to a few thousand so realisticly it's only gonna be a few bytes, but the protocol dictates it should be able to handle 255 msg bytes potentially. The data is Big Endian. The last two bytes are CRC bytes. Most Significant and Least Significant Byte.

Comment: No native Swift type will work for this if you have more than 8 bytes of message.

Comment: Correct. I guess I will have to work with 8 bytes of message to start with, it should do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an array :

```
let bytes: [UInt8] = [204, 74, 3, 0, 97, 168, 209, 239]
```

let's get the length of the message:

```
let length = Int(bytes[2])
```

`msg` is the variable that will store the result:

```
var msg = 0
```

`index` will point to the indexes of the octets of the whole message, from the LSB (higher index in `bytes`), to the MSB (lower index in `bytes`)

```
var index = bytes.count - 3
```

`power` is the power with which we'll be *shifting* the octets

```
var power = 1
```

Then we calculate the message this way :

```
while index > 2 {
    msg += Int(bytes[index]) * power
    power = power << 8
    index -= 1
}
```

The result is :

```
print(msg)  //25000
```

---

Or as **@JoshCaswell** suggests :

```
var msg: UInt64 = 0
var index = 3
while index < bytes.count - 2 {
    msg <<= 8 //msg = msg << 8
    msg += UInt64(bytes[index])
    index += 1
}
```

---

In both solutions, we suppose that the message can fit into an `Int` or `UInt64`

Comment: Might be best to use an explicitly-sized `UInt64` rather than the implicit `Int` for the result. Also, why keep the extra `power` variable around and do another multiplication rather than directly bitshifting `msg`?

Comment: Super minor, but there's also a `<<=` operator you can use instead of `msg = msg << 8`

Comment: This solves my problem perfectly and with such little code. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MariusGulbrandsen Glad to help, you could mark this answer as accepted by clicking the check mark next to it. see: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for more information

Comment: @Carpsen90 Done! If you don't mind, can you point me in a direction to understand why shifting the bits by 8 to the left make my decimal numbers combine ilke they would have been hecadecimal?

Comment: @MariusGulbrandsen When you say *combine* for example `0x61` and `0xA8` into `0x61A8`, it is as if `0x61`was shifted 8 bits to the left to become `0x6100` and then add `0xA8`. I hope it makes sense now :)

Comment: @Carpsen90 That makes sense! The only question I have then is that my numbers was dec [97, 168]. Wouldn't this process then make it 97168? What makes the compiler interpret them as hexadecimal instead? Thanks!

Comment: `97` and `168` are decimal numbers, but that's not how the machine represents them. They are represented as bits as you already know. Bit shifting with `<<` works on the binary representation, not the decimal one. `power << 8` is equivalent in the decimal world to multiplying by `256 = 2^8`, and not multiplying by powers of `10`

Comment: @Carpsen90 Because the binary representation of both hex and dec -numbers is of course the same, got it! Thank you for clearing this up for me, cheers! :)